# Mockito: check response Header and Status

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I have this junit test using Mockito (an open source testing framework for Java released under the MIT License) in a The Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework application
I have this methods in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/devices" } , method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} )
    public void initGetForm(@ModelAttribute("searchForm") final SearchForm searchForm,
                            HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response,
                            Locale locale) throws Exception {

        String newUrl = request.getContextPath() + "/devices/" + locale;

        if (locale !=null && isValid(locale)) {
            newUrl = request.getContextPath() + "/devices/" + DEFAULT_LOCALE;           
        } 

        redirectPermanently (response, newUrl);     

    }




    protected void redirectPermanently (HttpServletResponse response, String to) {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", to);
        response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
        }
```

and this is my Test class:

```
@Test
    public void testInitGetForm() throws Exception {

        controller.initGetForm(emptySearchForm(), request, response, null);

    }

@Before
public void setUpTest() {
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
}
```

Is it possible to check the Header and Status of the response ?????

Comment: This test does not use Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instances of [MockHttpServletResponse](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html) and [MockHttpServletRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) from spring-test module.
Pass them to your controller and then just check results using MockHttpServletResponse.getStatus() MockHttpServletResponse.containsHeader()
 methods.